# Sitecore: Exclude items during lucene search

Tags: lucene, sitecore

How can I use ADC during lucene search to exclude out unwanted items? (Given that I have few millions of items)
Given the unwanted items are different from time to time, thus, it is impossible for me to use the config file to exclude it out.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand you want to be able to manually set some of the items as excluded from appearing in search results.

The simplest solution would be to add some `Exclude` boolean flag to the base template and check for this flag while searching for the items.

The other solution is to create some settings page with `multilist` field for items excluded in the search and then pass ids of the selected items to the search query excluding them from the search.

Comment: I have the multilist field to hold all the unwanted items not to be searched. But how am I going to update the lucene for the items that I don't want?

Comment: Just iterate over the multilist values and add a new `TermQuery` with `ID` as a key and values from the list as terms with `Occur` set to `BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT`.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a pretty extensive overview of what you'll need to do to get this going. What it does is it prevents items that have a checkbox field checked in sitecore from ever even getting indexed. Sorry it's not easier!

Requirements: Advanced Database Crawler: http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Search_Contrib.aspx

1) Add a checkbox field to the base template in sitecore, titled "Exclude from Search" or whatever.

2) Create your custom index crawler that will index the new field.

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    class MyIndexCrawler : Sitecore.SharedSource.SearchCrawler.Crawlers.AdvancedDatabaseCrawler
    {
        protected override void AddSpecialFields(Lucene.Net.Documents.Document document, Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item)
        {
            base.AddSpecialFields(document, item);

            document.Add(CreateValueField("exclude from search",
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(item["Exclude From Search"]) 
                ? "0" 
                : "1"));
```

3) Configure Lucene to use a new custom index crawler (Web.config if you're not using includes)

```
<configuration>
  <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
    ...
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
      <master type="YourNameSpace.MyIndexCrawler,YourNameSpace">
        <Database>web</Database>
        <Root>/sitecore/content</Root>
        <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>
```

4) Configure your search query

```
var excludeQuery = new BooleanQuery();
Query exclude = new TermQuery(new Term("exclude from search", "0"));
excludeQuery.Add(exclude, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

5) Get your search  hits

```
var db = Sitecore.Context.Database;
var index = SearchManager.GetIndex("name_of_your_index"); // I use db.Name.ToLower() for my master/web indexes
var context = index.CreateSearchContext();
var searchContext = new SearchContext(db.GetItem(rootItem));

var hits = context.Search(excludeQuery, searchContext);
```

Note: You can obviously use a combined query here to get more flexibility on your searches!